Get ETH back from smart contract that was deployed almost a year ago
almost a year ago i fell for a contract scam and Im still confused if I CAN or cannot get the ETH back from it, its still sitting in the contract for almost 300+ days now.
code used in remix that was a scam https://pastebin.com/raw/idCCExmD
the contract 0xFB0E112cE10193E23C62c47F837c9DF968285c55
I need clarification I’m still contact creator and deployer yet can’t withdraw because of how it’s set up? Is there no way I can some how self destruct the contract to get my eth? there is a withdraw function

I had a peek at the code. It looks like a traditional scam contract.
Unfortunately, there's most likely no way for you to get your assets back. The contract only allows withdrawals to the attacker's address.
Do note that I didn't analyze the contract very deeply, so there's a very small chance that there is some way, but I really doubt it.
